# How can I loop through a python dictionary and replace a substring value?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary, replace

I want to loop through a dictionary with unknown keys and replace a specific substring value.

```
mydict = {
    'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': 
    [
        '+-BROKEN- http://www.broken.com/',
        '+---OK--- http://www.set.com/',
        '+---OK--- http://www.one.com/'
    ],
    'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': 
    [
        '+-BROKEN- http://www.broken.com/'
    ]
}

val = "+-BROKEN-"

for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
   if v.contains(val):
     v.replace(val, '')
```

The result I want is:

```
{
    'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/':
    [
        'http://www.broken.com/',
        '+---OK--- http://www.set.com/',
        '+---OK--- http://www.one.com/'
    ], 
    'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': 
    [
        'http://www.broken.com/'
    ]
}
```

How can I loop through a dictionary and replace a specific substring value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working like you expect because `v` is a list, not a single string.  For that reason, `v.contains(val)` is always `False`.  One way to accomplish what you're describing would be:

```
for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
  for i, s in enumerate(v):
    if val in s:
      v[i] = s.replace(val, '')
```

Comment: This looks great. I'm getting an error, though, because I have an odd character in the string: ├─BROKEN─    error is: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) I tried s = '├─BROKEN─' val = unicode(s, "utf-8") but same error. Any advice? I'm using 2.7

Comment: You might try `s = u'├─BROKEN─'` and see if that does anything for you.  You might also try something like finding an example that contains the value you want to replace and assigning it based on a substring.  Something like `val = mydict.values()[0][0][:10]` to get the first ten characters of the first entry in the first list in the dict, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dictionary values are all lists which contain strings and you want to remove the value from any string containing it, you could try:

```
for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
    mydict[k] = [string.replace(val,'')] for string in v]
```